# Set Concentric Circles Within a Text-box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to keep these two circles concentric but not have them interfere with the text and stuff on the web page. I am currently using `position: fixed`, but I want them within a textbox below that can also limit the size of the circles so that they don't take up the whole screen if user inputs something unreasonable value.

*EDIT:

I am now trying to make it so that when an input value of 85 or greater is inputted into outer diameter on jsFiddle or "Pipe O.D." on the actual web page, an error message/some time of message pops up saying "Too big".

Additionally, on the web page itself, there is a calculator button using Formidable Forms. After hitting calculate, it displays the output calculated values, but when the values of the inputs are changed, the circles no longer change size until the page is refreshed. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Actual webpage being used on: https://schallertenterprises.com/cutter-travel-calculator/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.circle').hide();
  $('#outer_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $converted = ($outer_diameter * 10).toFixed(3);
    console.log($outer_diameter, $converted);
    $('.circle').css({
      height: (2 * $converted),
      width: (2 * $converted),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
    $('#error').hide();
  })

  $('.circle2').hide();
  $('#inner_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $inner_diameter = parseFloat($("#inner_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $converted_2 = (($outer_diameter * 10) - ($inner_diameter * 10)).toFixed(3);
    console.log($inner_diameter, $converted_2);
    $('.circle2').css({
      height: (2 * $converted_2),
      width: (2 * $converted_2),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle2').fadeIn(300);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.circle2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>
      Cutter Calculator
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="Calculations">
    <input type="number" id="outer_diameter" placeholder="Enter Outer Diameter"> <br>
    <input type="number" id="inner_diameter" placeholder="Enter Thickness"> <br>
    <input type="button" id="bttn" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
  </div>
  <div class="circles">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <span class="circle2"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/6rc9jbo3/3/

Actual webpage being used on: https://schallertenterprises.com/cutter-travel-calculator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something

```
    .circles
    {
      margin-top:15px;
      position:relative
    }
    .circle {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: blue;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      z-index: -1;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      position:absolute;
    }

    .circle2 {
      display: inline-block;
      position:absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: red;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      z-index: -1;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
    }
```

```js
      $('#outer_diameter').on('change', function() {
        var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
        var $converted = ($outer_diameter * 10).toFixed(3);
        console.log($outer_diameter, $converted);
        $('.circle').css({
          height: (2 * $converted),
          width: (2 * $converted),
          top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
          left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
        });
        $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
        $('.circles').css({height:(2 * $converted) + 10, width: (2 * $converted) + 10})
        $('#error').hide();
      })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4w6gzov/7/

Basically
I added in the css:

`position:relative` to the `.circles`

and `position:absolute` to the `.circle` and `.circle2`

And for the js, I added:

```js
$('.circles').css({height:(2 * $converted) + 10, width: (2 * $converted) + 10})
```

finally, to limit the use (as for the size), you just need to add a small condition in the `change` event and if the input is too big, just do nothing and notify the user.

Hope this helped

Comment: This helps a bit thank you! How come you added the js? I don't understand what it changes in relation to the current js I have

Comment: Also how would I add the condition in the change event? I am a bit new to js/html

Comment: For example if(converted <= SOMEVALUE) {Do your things} else {don't}. The Js is making sure the circle don't overlap on your form fields. It creates an invisible box. You can add the css property "border: 1px solid #000;" to see what it does.